# iCloud key value storage doesn't appear in Manage Storage in iCloud iPhone Setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

i have enabled iCloud key value storage, and i have add some value,then i do this:

```
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
```

to synchronize the data and then i have checked on another device and the key value i have stored is in the cloud, but if i go in my iPhone in:

`Settings->iCloud->Storage & Backup->Manage Storage`

but my app it isn't in the list of app use iCloud, why? how i can see how space i have used?

Comment: Have you enabled Entitlements for your project? Have you enabled iCloud in App configuration or created updated provisioning profile

Comment: yes it's all active in all profile...

Comment: if i check on another device, i can see the value i have stored, so i think it's well configured...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the UIDocument appears in that view.